# Symfony 5: How to get isVerified User in authenticator

Tags: symfony, symfony5

i'm still a beginner in symfony so i hope my question will be fastly answered. I did a lot of research on internet without finding anything about my problem.

I use Symfony 5.3 basic authenticator which is generated when we do the bin/console make:auth with maker bundle. All basic config, i didn't touch anything in security.yaml. The thing i want to perform is set a authentication error if the user is not verified by Email. My User entity is very basic too with make:user. But it seems like the User representation we get with this token in onAuthenticationSuccess doesn't contain any "isVerified" method, an interesting fact is that he doesn't contain any "getEmail" method too, seems like he just contain the main accessors (username, password). Any solution ?

(Login is actually working, i just can't perform this verifying trick.)

EDIT: Just saw that "isVerifed" and "getEmail" methods can't be called from any $this->getUser() in controllers too. But when we do a new User(), we can call these methods.

EDIT AGAIN: Ok it's because $this->getUser() and $token->getUser() extends UserInterface and there's not any getEmail() or isVerified() method in this interface. So what is the trick ? I keep investigating.

Authenticator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class Authenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
use TargetPathTrait;

public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
{
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
}

public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
{
    $parameters = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($parameters['username']),
        new PasswordCredentials($parameters['password'])
    );
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if (!$token->getUser()->isVerified()) { //isVerified show "undefined method"
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, "You are not verified. Check your emails.");
    }

    return null;
}

protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
{
    return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
}
}
```

My User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserSymfangularRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserSymfangularRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 */
class UserSymfangular implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];

/**
 * @var string The hashed password
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isVerified = false;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUserIdentifier(): string
{
    return (string) $this->username;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
 */
public function getPassword(): string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
 * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getSalt(): ?string
{
    return null;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
    // $this->plainPassword = null;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getIsVerified(): ?bool
{
    return $this->isVerified;
}

public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
{
    $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

    return $this;
}

public function isVerified(): bool
{
    return $this->isVerified;
}
```

}

EDIT: Solved it. Actually i can do $this->getUser()->getEmail() or $this->getUser()->isVerified(), but the methods just doesn't appear in the autocomplete of my VSCode. Sorry for all of this.

Comment: What is the type of `$token->getUser()`? Can you put there something like `var_dump(is_object($token->getUser()) ? get_class($token->getUser()) : gettype($token->getUser()));`? Is it your class? If not, can you show us the `security.yaml` file?

Comment: Hello @Rikudou_Sennin, sorry i was very busy so i could not answer earlier. I edited my thread, i'm still stuck.

Comment: Hi @Nevermore1803, 

I had the same problem and stumbled upon your question. 

Have you checked the [UserCheckerInterface?](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html)

It seems it's doing the exact thing we are looking for.

Cheers